# Printing string in hex?

Tags: c, string, hex

Is this short way for printing the string in hex is correct? If not, how it should be fixed?

```
uint8_t *m = string;
int c = sizeof(string);
while(c--){
    printf("%02x ", *(m++));
}
```

Comment: What makes you ask this question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No "oneliner", no. Besides, your code looks broken.

You can't use `sizeof` like that, you probably mean `strlen()`.

And you need to cast the character to an unsigned type to be safe.

So, something like this, perhaps:

```
void print_hex(const char *s)
{
  while(*s)
    printf("%02x", (unsigned int) *s++);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Note that I *don't* call `strlen()`, since there's no point in iterating over the string twice when once will do. :)

Comment: `sizeof` may be fine if he's dealing with a plain array, e.g. `uint8_t string[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };`. However, his could would have an off-by-one (the `while` loops reads one character too much.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe yes i'am having a uint8_t[] here... better use `while(--c)` in my case? but then the \00 isnt printed...

Comment: @reox: Sorry, I miscounted. I had an off-by-one in my thinking, so to say ;-) I think `while(c--`) would be fine. However, if the array is always null-terminated you may just as well not use the `c` variable at all but rather just use `while(*m)`.

Comment: Can someone turn this into a function that returns a const char instead of printf?

Answer (score 3):

I think technically "string" is misleading here; you seem to be printing an array (not necessarily null-terminated) of `uint8_t` values.

You will need a loop in any case. If you can use C99, you could write

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(string); ++i) printf("%02x", string[i]);
```

If the array *is* null-terminated, *and* you don't need the original value of `string` (this is often a case when passing the pointer by value), you could have

```
static void printArray(const uint8_t *string)
{
  while (*string) printf("%02x", *string++);
}
```