# how to print contents of a void *?

Tags: c, types

```
static inline uint256_t sha256(const void *data, size_t len)
{
    secp256k1_sha256_t cxt;
    secp256k1_sha256_initialize(&cxt);
    secp256k1_sha256_write(&cxt, (uint8_t *)data, (int)len);
    uint256_t res;
    secp256k1_sha256_finalize(&cxt, (uint8_t *)&res);
    return res;
}
```

I want to see what's inside ***data*** and what's being returned by the above function, so printing seems like an easy way but how do i print contents of `*data` not the pointer to ***data*** because `*%p*` gave me an address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
const unsigned char *bytes = data;
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  printf("%02X ", bytes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to print the pointer address:

```
printf("%p", data);
```

2. If you want to print the value (data), then you need to cast the pointer to something else, probably a (const char *).  Used a "%s" which would work well if data is string:

```
printf("%*s", (int) len, (const char *) data);
```

If your data is binary or contain '\0' bytes then you probably [hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725107/printing-string-in-hex) encoding instead.

Comment: `"%*s"` work well with a _string_, as it stops printing when a byte 0 encountered - or `len` bytes.  To certainly print `len` bytes takes other code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yup, I will spell it out even more.